# Relationship of refractive indices in three materials

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

[image]

The above paragraph is trying to use the principle of least time to relate the refractive indices in three materials. How do we know that $v_2 = \frac{v_1}{v_3}$ and $v_3 =  \frac{v_1}{v_2}$? (in the equation)

with $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ be speed of light in air, water and glass respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have quoted is a simple manipulation of fractions:

$$ n_{23} = \frac{v_2}{v_3} = \frac{1/v_3}{1/v_2} = \frac{v_1}{v_1} \cdot \frac{1/v_3}{1/v_2} = \frac{v_1/v_3}{v_1/v_2} = \frac{n_{13}}{n_{12}}. $$

The *ratio* of $v_2$ and $v_3$ is equal to the second-right-most fraction you see above. They are *not* necessarily equal to the numerator and the denominator respectively.

Comment: I see. But why $v_2$ can be expressed into $1/v_3$? (and vice versa)

Comment: It's not. $v_2$ and $1/(1/v_2)$ are mathematically equivalent. It's like writing $ 3 + 2 = 2 + 3$. Same for $v_3$ but in the denominator.